# Providing defaults to destructured match arms in Rust

Tags: rust

Lets say I have an enum like this:

```
enum C {
   A(i64, i64),
   B(i64),
}
```

And I want to match on it with default values.  Is there a way I an do something like so that would allow me to match multiple arms with default values:

```rust
fn main() {
    let var = C::B(1);
    
    match var {
        C::A(v1, v2) | C::B(v1, v2 @ 0) => {
            assert_eq!((v1, v2), (1, 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the tuple (double parentheses) inside `A`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible shortly.

Comment: bury it and never think about it later https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e3fad3cf65dfa5ad9aa8f83c25d4241

Answer (score 3):

You can match against tuple `(var, v2_default)` instead of just against var:

```rust
match (var, 0) {
    (C::A(v1, v2), _) | (C::B(v1), v2) => {
        println!("{} {}", v1, v2);
    }
}
```